# Custom Token Authentication with Craft 3 Login Form

Tags: craft3, php

I am building token auth system in Craft 3.
https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/examples/login-form.html
I used this Login Form.

Now I am going to create my own token and save it in user profile.

First problem is to link this Form Submit Action to my custom action.
I can not find the controller linked to this action.

How can I customize my login system? Where can I find the controller for the built-in login form logic?

Answer (score 3):

The submit action is the **actionInput** input `{{ actionInput('users/login') }}`.
This will call the login method of the [src/controllers/UsersController](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/d19e2f549c58b1f6aded350b1ad6b8258c674bfa/src/controllers/UsersController.php#L121) and perform the action.

You may also take a look at [User Element & Events](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-elements-user.html) where you can listen on various user events like `EVENT_BEFORE_VALIDATE`, `EVENT_BEFORE_AUTHENTICATE` etc.

Comment: I don't have the UsersController file in my project. How can I append my code into the UsersController file? So that I can edit the login action in order to create custom token and save it in user profile like here.
`$user->setFieldValue('token', $token);`

Comment: Should I have to add this file?
https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/d19e2f549c58b1f6aded350b1ad6b8258c674bfa/src/controllers/UsersController.php

Comment: I want to keep the login system and only append token to the current login. @christopher